# using SOAP for Xamarin Login and Register

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin

How possible is this? is it possible to use Webservices with Xamarin? I have been trying to implement Login and Register without using WCF, just a simple SOAP Webservice. I have not seen any leads with this hence i wanted to ask has anyone implemented something like this.

Comment: Possible, yes.  But I would absolutely avoid it if possible.  REST services are much, much easier to deal with.

Comment: I have not seen any good tutorials on how to use DB with xamarin. especially the part of Login and register

Comment: Your question is about SOAP services, not DB.

Comment: Well yes. I have not seen any SOAP that i can use to connect to DB and access the DB from xamarin.forms, that has been my worry

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/

Comment: Saw that does not really give a headstart for me

Comment: If you're having a specific problem then you ask about the specific problem.  But just saying "I read the docs and I don't understand" is way too broad for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @Jin Hi ,you can first have a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/web-service/?tabs=vswin) .